# Non-negative and differentiable concave functions and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$

Tags: limits, analysis

Let $f : [0,\infty) \mapsto [0,\infty)$ be concave and differentiable on $(0,+\infty)$ with $f(0)= 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for every $x > 0$.

It is clear that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f'(x)}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}$ exist in $\mathbb{R}_+$ since $x \mapsto f'(x)$ and $x \mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ are non-increasing and bounded below by $0$.

Besides it is easy to show that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f'(x)}$ and for every $x >0$, $\frac{f(x)}{x} \geq f'(x)$.

> **My question is:**
>
> Does the limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{f'(x)}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}}$ always exist in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: I don't think the limit need exist. Consider for example if $f'(x)=\frac12$ for a while, then $f'(x)=\frac14$ for a long time, then $f'(x)=\frac18$ for a very long time, then $f'(x)=\frac1{16}$ for an extremely long time ... the quotient would oscillate between $\frac12$ and $1$ infinitely often.

Comment: Is this function concave? Is it differentiable on (0 $\infty)$?

Comment: Thank you Greg, in your counter-example $f$ can be concave but seems almost everywhere differentiable. However It seems also possible to build a similar counter-example which is  differentiable on $(0, +\infty)$.